# Can anyone explain Nilsson's sequence score in 8-puzzle more clearly?

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I am learning A* algorithm on 8-puzzle problem.

I don't have questions about A*, but have some for the heuristic score -  Nilsson's sequence score.

[Justin Heyes-Jones web pages - A* Algorithm](http://www.heyes-jones.com/astar.html) explains A* very clearly. It has a picture for Nilsson's sequence scores.

[image: Nilsson's sequence scores]

It explains:

**Nilsson's sequence score**

> A tile in the center scores `1` (since it should be empty)
>
> For each tile not in the center, if the tile clockwise to it is not the one that should be clockwise to it then score `2`.
>
> Multiply this sequence by three and finally add the total distance you need to move each tile back to its correct position.

I can't understand the steps above for calculating the scores.

For example, for the start state, what `h = 17`?

```
+---+---+---+
|   | A | C |
+---+---+---+
| H | B | D |
+---+---+---+
| G | F | E |
+---+---+---+
```

So, by following the description,  `B` is in the center, so we have a score of `1`.

Then

> For each title not in the center, if the **tile** clockwise to **it** is not the one that should be clockwise to it then score `2`.

I am not sure what does this statement mean. What does the bolded **tile** refer to?  What does the bolded **it** refer to? Does the bolded **it** refer to the center title (B in this example)? Or does it refer to each tile not in the center?

Is the next step that we start from `A`, so `C` should not be clockwise to `A`, then we have a score of `2`. And then `B` should be clockwise to `A`, then we ignore, so on so forth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us number the squares as follows:

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 7 | 8 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 5 | 4 |
+---+---+---+
```

Now, let `N(x)` be the current square number for tile `x`. So, for example, if a tile `A` is in the square number `3`, then `N(A) = 3`. Note that a "tile" can be in any of these squares and the number of each square remains the same (so the upper left square will always be the number `0`).

The sequence score is given by:

```
for each tile x in (A, B, C, ..., H)
    score += distance from N(x) to the correct square for tile x
    if N(x) == 8  # i.e. the tile is in the center
       score += 3*1
    else if N(next(x)) != (N(x) + 1) % 8
       score += 3*2
```

where `next(x)` takes `x` to the next letter, i.e. `next(A) = B, next(B) = C, ... , next(G) = H, next(H) = A`.

So to answer your specific questions:

1. **tile** refers to the tile on square `(N(x) + 1) % 8`, i.e. the next square round the edge
2. **it** refers to the tile in "for each tile not in the center"
3. The next step is given by looking at `A`.  `C` should not be clockwise to `A`, then we have `2`. Next we look at `C`, `D` should be clockwise to `A`, so this is okay. Looking at `D, E, F` and `G` all of these are okay, but when we get to `H` it should not be next to 0, so we have a score of `4`.  We add 1 because `B` is in the center to get `5`.  Then multiply by `3` to get `15`.  Then add `1` to move `B` up to the right place, and `1` to move `A` left to the right place for a final total of `17`.